# Can't import tensorflow 2.x with spyder (any version): Tensorflow_core.estimator problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

I have different conda environments for different tensorflow and pytorch versions. They all work without issues when calling python on the terminal.

I can also use them with Spyder, either with an individual Spyder installation in each conda environment, or using the "modular approach" described here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder

BUT, every attempt to import tensorflow with spyder fails when dealing with tensorflow 2.x , always with the same error of failing to import the module `tensorflow_core.estimator`

```
Error in callback <bound method AutoreloadMagics.post_execute_hook of <autoreload.AutoreloadMagics object at 0x7f41b8711990>> (for post_execute):
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf2_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions/autoreload.py", line 538, in post_execute_hook
    _, pymtime = self._reloader.filename_and_mtime(sys.modules[modname])

  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf2_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions/autoreload.py", line 184, in filename_and_mtime
    if not hasattr(module, '__file__') or module.__file__ is None:

  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf2_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()

  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf2_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)

  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf2_env/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'
```

This issue is particular for tensorflow 2 (2.0 and 2.1) and Spyder (version 3, 4 and 5).

I haven't been able to find a way of making this work, and I have no idea why Spyder tries to load the module `tensorflow_core.estimator` when importing tensorflow, or why this is not an error when importing tensorflow with python from the terminal. This is NOT an environment problem: All other modules in the environment are present and can be imported with Spyder.

Issues with this module are not uncommon, but I haven't seen a single solution:

[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator' for tensorflow 2.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022256/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-core-estimator-for-tensorflow)

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34607

https://www.reddit.com/r/tensorflow/comments/jesmaq/how_to_resolve_no_module_named_tensorflow/

https://nomodulenamed.com/m/tensorflow_core.python.autograph.core.config_lib

Comment: reinstalling tensorflow might help

Comment: @jakub it did not. I have reinstalled tensorflow and different versions. Whenever tensorflow 2.x is present, I can't import it with spyder failing with the same error.

Comment: You can also create a new conda environment and install tensorflow there. How did you install tensorflow? Via conda? Pip?

Comment: @jakub everything was installed using conda

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED: There was a version mismatch between tensorflow-gpu and tensorflow-estimator

When installing tensorflow-gpu=2.x , for some reason, a mismatching tensorflow-estimator version was being downloaded. For tensorflow-gpu=2.1, tensorflow-estimator=2.4 was being downloaded. Downgrading this to tensorflow-estimator=2.1 solved the import issue in Spyder.

Why Spyder imports tensorflow-estimator whereas Python itself doesn't is still unresolved.
And why this version mismatch is happening after tensorflow-gpu=2.x is also unresolved.

Comment: Downgrading tensorflow-estimator to 2.1 to match the downloaded version of tensorflow (2.1) also solved this issue for me. But I am not sure Spyder was the source of download version mismatch as I downloaded the packages from Anaconda Prompt and was only loading them in Spyder.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall everything tensorflow-related.

```
$ pip uninstall tensorflow-estimator \
  tensorboard tb-nightly tf-estimator-nightly
```

Then install the packages again.  This usually fixes it.

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32952

**Edit:** If you have installed Spyder from the Anaconda, go to the Anaconda launcher. There go to environments, you will see two of them: root and tensorflow. The latter one is created due to the instructions by tensorflow.org. Just run all those instructions on the root, don't activate tensorflow environment, it will work. Everything will be available in spyder.

Comment: those lines will only uninstall the tensorflow-estimator and tensorboard modules right? Not "everything tensorflow related". Also we are dealing with very specific version dependencies, so "just installing" could mean a lot of different combinations of versions. Additionally, tensorflow is working perfectly, I can run code when calling python from the terminal, the issue seems to be related to Spyder. I have reinstalled tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, and tensorboard several times and does not fix the issue

Comment: Your edit suggests that Spyder is not being activated in the proper environment and cant load the modules, but as stated in the question, this is not the case. Spyder is correctly launched in the desired environment and has access to all modules within that environment. It only breaks when loading tensorflow

Comment: that's not true, I'm specifically saying that it's an issue with the tensorflow env