# Tensorflow_core estimator not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to import an excel file into my notebook, using pandas as code shown below

```
**#importing the data of subject 1 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\henda\OneDrive\Desktop\Collection\Research\Germany\2D Data\Subject 1 (Jan lau)\Train.xlsx')   
#print (df)**
```

I keep getting this error , although i tried some of the fixes suggested in some similar post nothing worked for me.

```
***File "C:\Users\henda\anaconda3\envs\Seq2Seq1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'***
```

can anyone help?
I also tried downgrading my tensor flow estimator but didnt work

Comment: You can try the answer suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022256/) StackOverflow post, this should resolve your issue.

Comment: I tried doing that but it didnt work , And i dont seem to know why

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Check your `tensorflow-estimator`, and `tensorflow` to verify if they are of the same version using this code:

```
import tensorflow
print(tensorflow.__version__)

import tensorflow-estimator
print(tensorflow-estimator.__version__)
```

E.g. if `tensorflow`  version is `2.1.0`, let `tensorflow-estimator`, also be of version `2.1.0`. It might mean you upgrading or downgrading to balance the two. In my case, `tensorflow` version was `2.1.0`, and my  `tensorflow-estimator` version was `2.5.0`. Downgrading `tensorflow-estimator` version to `2.1.0` worked.