# why it can't import trace in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following error, and I am new to data science and python
I am using python, keras, tensorflow

```
from tensorflow.python.profiler import trace
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'trace'

Full error report

```
Training network heads
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\tensorboard_v1.py", line 96, in __init__
    from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import compiler
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\compiler\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.compiler import jit
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\compiler\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.compiler import xla
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\compiler\xla.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator import model_fn as model_fn_lib
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\estimator\model_fn.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import model_fn
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1 import estimator
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import experimental
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\experimental\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import estimator
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.profiler import trace
ImportError: cannot import name 'trace'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-6-712e23ddfaeb>", line 8, in <module>
    layers='heads')
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdai-mapping-challenge-mask-rcnn-master\crowdai-mapping-challenge-mask-rcnn-master\mrcnn\model.py", line 2287, in train
    histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=False),
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\tensorboard_v1.py", line 98, in __init__
    raise ImportError('You need the TensorFlow (v1) module installed to '
ImportError: You need the TensorFlow (v1) module installed to use TensorBoard.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1169, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 316, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 350, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\inspect.py", line 1490, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\inspect.py", line 1448, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\tensorboard_v1.py", line 96, in __init__
    from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import compiler
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\compiler\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.compiler import jit
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\compiler\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.compiler import xla
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\compiler\xla.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator import model_fn as model_fn_lib
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\estimator\model_fn.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import model_fn
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1 import estimator
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import experimental
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\experimental\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import estimator
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.profiler import trace
ImportError: cannot import name 'trace'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-6-712e23ddfaeb>", line 8, in <module>
    layers='heads')
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdai-mapping-challenge-mask-rcnn-master\crowdai-mapping-challenge-mask-rcnn-master\mrcnn\model.py", line 2287, in train
    histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=False),
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\tensorboard_v1.py", line 98, in __init__
    raise ImportError('You need the TensorFlow (v1) module installed to '
ImportError: You need the TensorFlow (v1) module installed to use TensorBoard.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3263, in run_ast_nodes
    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3360, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2047, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1436, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1336, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1193, in structured_traceback
    tb_offset)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1150, in format_exception_as_a_whole
    last_unique, recursion_repeat = find_recursion(orig_etype, evalue, records)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 451, in find_recursion
    return len(records), 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1169, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 316, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 350, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\inspect.py", line 1490, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\inspect.py", line 1448, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\tensorboard_v1.py", line 96, in __init__
    from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import compiler
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\compiler\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.compiler import jit
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\compiler\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.compiler import xla
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\compiler\xla.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.estimator import model_fn as model_fn_lib
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\estimator\model_fn.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import model_fn
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1 import estimator
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import experimental
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\_api\v1\estimator\experimental\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import estimator
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.profiler import trace
ImportError: cannot import name 'trace'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-6-712e23ddfaeb>", line 8, in <module>
    layers='heads')
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdai-mapping-challenge-mask-rcnn-master\crowdai-mapping-challenge-mask-rcnn-master\mrcnn\model.py", line 2287, in train
    histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=False),
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks\tensorboard_v1.py", line 98, in __init__
    raise ImportError('You need the TensorFlow (v1) module installed to '
ImportError: You need the TensorFlow (v1) module installed to use TensorBoard.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3263, in run_ast_nodes
    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3360, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2047, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1436, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1336, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1193, in structured_traceback
    tb_offset)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1150, in format_exception_as_a_whole
    last_unique, recursion_repeat = find_recursion(orig_etype, evalue, records)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 451, in find_recursion
    return len(records), 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2895, in _run_cell
    return runner(coro)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    coro.send(None)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3072, in run_cell_async
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3282, in run_ast_nodes
    self.showtraceback()
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2047, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1436, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1336, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1211, in structured_traceback
    chained_exceptions_tb_offset)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1150, in format_exception_as_a_whole
    last_unique, recursion_repeat = find_recursion(orig_etype, evalue, records)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 451, in find_recursion
    return len(records), 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1169, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 316, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 350, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\inspect.py", line 1490, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\inspect.py", line 1448, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "F:\Khalid\Documents\miniconda3\envs\crowdAI2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'
```

Comment: sounds like `tensorflow.python.profiler` doesn't contain `trace`. I found: `tensorflow.profiler.experimental.Trace` and one more: `tensorflow.autograph.trace`

Comment: you are right, I was training on this code  https://github.com/crowdAI/crowdai-mapping-challenge-mask-rcnn/blob/master/Training.ipynb but I don't know how to solve it

Comment: some advised me to upgrade to tensorflow 2.x but it showed more error than this version also the requirement file recommend tensorflow 1.x

Comment: the version you choose should depend on other packages you are using, nad hardware it's compatible with, not just random newest or something similar

Comment: Hello @KhalidElejla, please format your code and errors to help others help you.

Comment: @Guglie thanks I have added the full error, can you please help me, I am stuck in this code for a week

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022256/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-core-estimator-for-tensorflow) reference help you to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the Tensorflow version

```
pip install tensorflow --upgrade
```

In Tensorflow 2.7.0. Use

```
from tensorflow.profiler.experimental import Trace
```

Comment: what if you need to use tensorflow 1?