# ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module. Below is the traceback from this internal error

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, gpu

I want to calculate the following CNN.

I launched the Jupyter notebook via Anaconda.
The calculation should be done via the GPU.

Unfortunately, I got the following error message. Any Ideas regarding my issue?

```
    history = model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch= len(train_generator)//batch_size,
    
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=val_generator,
        validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
        callbacks=callbacks)
    
        WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
          ...
            to  
          ['...']
        
        WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
          ...
            to  
          ['...']
        
        WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
          ...
            to  
          ['...']
        
        WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
          ...
            to  
          ['...']
        
        Train for 44 steps, validate for 130 steps
        Epoch 1/5
         1/44 [..............................] - ETA: 7:40
        
        ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
        Below is the traceback from this internal error.
        
        ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
        Below is the traceback from this internal error.
        
        ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
        Below is the traceback from this internal error.
        
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-19-af7d18342167>", line 8, in <module>
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 819, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 342, in fit
    total_epochs=epochs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 128, in run_one_epoch
    batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 98, in execution_function
    distributed_function(input_fn))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 568, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 632, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 2363, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1611, in _filtered_call
    self.captured_inputs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1692, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 545, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[7,96,524,524] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[node sequential_1/conv2d_3/Conv2D (defined at <ipython-input-19-af7d18342167>:8) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_distributed_function_1811]

Function call stack:
distributed_function


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ResourceExhaustedError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1169, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 316, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 350, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\inspect.py", line 1490, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\inspect.py", line 1448, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-19-af7d18342167>", line 8, in <module>
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 819, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 342, in fit
    total_epochs=epochs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 128, in run_one_epoch
    batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 98, in execution_function
    distributed_function(input_fn))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 568, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 632, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 2363, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1611, in _filtered_call
    self.captured_inputs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1692, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 545, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[7,96,524,524] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[node sequential_1/conv2d_3/Conv2D (defined at <ipython-input-19-af7d18342167>:8) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_distributed_function_1811]

Function call stack:
distributed_function


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ResourceExhaustedError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3263, in run_ast_nodes
    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3360, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2047, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1436, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1336, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1193, in structured_traceback
    tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1150, in format_exception_as_a_whole
    last_unique, recursion_repeat = find_recursion(orig_etype, evalue, records)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 451, in find_recursion
    return len(records), 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1169, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 316, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 350, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\inspect.py", line 1490, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\inspect.py", line 1448, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-19-af7d18342167>", line 8, in <module>
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 819, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 342, in fit
    total_epochs=epochs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 128, in run_one_epoch
    batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 98, in execution_function
    distributed_function(input_fn))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 568, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 632, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 2363, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1611, in _filtered_call
    self.captured_inputs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1692, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 545, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[7,96,524,524] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[node sequential_1/conv2d_3/Conv2D (defined at <ipython-input-19-af7d18342167>:8) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_distributed_function_1811]

Function call stack:
distributed_function


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ResourceExhaustedError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3263, in run_ast_nodes
    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3360, in run_code
    self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2047, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1436, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1336, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1193, in structured_traceback
    tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1150, in format_exception_as_a_whole
    last_unique, recursion_repeat = find_recursion(orig_etype, evalue, records)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 451, in find_recursion
    return len(records), 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2895, in _run_cell
    return runner(coro)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    coro.send(None)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3072, in run_cell_async
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3282, in run_ast_nodes
    self.showtraceback()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2047, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1436, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1336, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1211, in structured_traceback
    chained_exceptions_tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1150, in format_exception_as_a_whole
    last_unique, recursion_repeat = find_recursion(orig_etype, evalue, records)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 451, in find_recursion
    return len(records), 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2044, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1169, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 316, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 350, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\inspect.py", line 1490, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\inspect.py", line 1448, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\PythonGPU\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'
```

Comment: A similar question has been asked, you might find this useful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022256/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-core-estimator-for-tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with installed TensorFlow version and other existing modules version mismatch in your system.

Please reinstall the upgraded TensorFlow version and restart the kernel in the existing conda environment.

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Also, please avoid using `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` in model training, because the model calculates these steps automatically while training if batch size is given.